# Communication via Lan from AIX to windows

Tags: linux, aix, lan

I have an AIX server in which I run a script periodically, originally, I wanted this script to send an email using mailx, but i've just been told that the server has no internet connection, just a lan connection. Is there a way to send a message or a signal from this script to a windows machine connected in the same network? I tried using "nc" and "netcat" but I've found no success with them.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: As long as it has an IP address you should be able to communicate with it. It doesn't need an Internet connection. It's like using an intercom -- you don't need to be connected to the public phone system.

Comment: Hey Barmar, yeah I can connect to the windows machine, but what I want is for it to know im trying to connect and do something afterwards.

Comment: It depends on what network services are running on the Windows machine.

Comment: ServerFault.com or SuperUser.com would be better places for this question, it's not a programming question.